# Is it possible to securely use OAuth2 on client applications without having to re-enter user credentials frequently?

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, client

I'm trying to authenticate multiple client applications with a backend REST API using OAuth2. I have three completely separate entities: backend API server, front-end Javascript app, and distributed mobile app. The clients are first-party applications, so they will take direct username/password input to generate access tokens.

So my question is: is it possible to authenticate to the backend REST API from these clients using OAuth2, without having re-enter user credentials every hour when the access token expires? I can't think of a solution that gives the access token a one-hour expiration, but yet seamlessly refresh the access token in the background without additional user input.

Yes, I know about setting an encrypted HTTP-only cookie containing the refresh token. That works fine for the Javascript app, but does nothing for the mobile app. Or any other non-web client that may pop up.

I thought that I had come up with a great idea, which was to use an additional authentication server to negotiate the authentication on behalf of the client. So, the client would send the authentication server the username/password, and the authentication server would then call the API, save the access/refresh token, and finally give the access token to the client application. The idea being that when the access token expires, the client could then send the access token to the authentication server, which looks up the refresh token, calls the API to get a new access token, and returns the new access token. The client has now refreshed its access token without ever knowing the refresh token.

But then I realized that I am essentially nullifying the existence of a refresh token, and instead trading an expired access token for a new access token. Unless I'm wrong, that is not really any better than just straight up giving the client the refresh token - if an attacker obtained an access token, he could forever have more access tokens.

Based on my research, I am coming to the conclusion that what I want to achieve is simply not possible. In that case, is the only possible method of having a persistent login to increase the access token's expiration time? That is a very poor outcome, in my opinion. *Surely* some other solution exists, right?!

Comment: The advantage of use `refresh_token` is your customer don't need to enter credentials again. So your app (or backend) can exchange the `refresh_token` by a new `token` transparently to your customer.

Comment: Right. But the issue is that since these are not trustworthy clients, they cannot store the refresh token - because anyone can see it.